# How does the Google PlayStore handle app permission changes?

Tags: android, google-play

The Google Play Store groups apps into three different categories:

- Updates
- Manual Updates
- Up To Date

How would the app store handle the following scenario?

1. Publish app (Version 1) with permission **android.permission.INTERNET**
2. Publish update (Version 2) with permissions **android.permission.INTERNET** and **android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE**
   --> The app is now put into *Manual Updates* because the permissions have changed.
3. Publish another update (Version 3) removing the **android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE** (so permissions are reset to the state of *1*)

***Question 1:***

If the user **has not** updated the app in the meantime (is still on Version 1), will the app stay in the *Manual Updates* group or will it be put back into *Updates* (since the permissions have been reset to initial state)?

***Question 2:***

If the user is already on Version 2, will the app be listed under *Updates* or *Manual Updates* (permissions have changed, but it's one permission less than before)?

It's really hard to test these scenarios. So I hope someone has experienced this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've just recreated both scenarios with a test app and got the following results:

**Scenario 1:**
The app will be moved back from the *Manual Updates* section into the *(Automatic) Updates* section.

**Scenario 2:**
No matter if the number of permissions increases or decreases, the app will always be listed under *Manual Updates* so that the user has to accept the permission changes manually.

Answer (score 0):

***Question 1:***
I believe the app will be in the *update* and not in the *manual update* category but I'm not 100% sure.

***Question 2:***
I know for a fact that even when removing permissions the app will be in the *manual update* category. It happened to me before.